# Why aren't my push and pop methods working?

Tags: perl, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack in Perl where I have an array. I want to push items on the array, pop items out and print out the new array like so: "1,2,3,5,6

How can I do that? My code just adds the number 6 to the top of the array.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

@array = 1..5;
push @array, 6; #Push the number 6 into the array 
pop @array, 4; #Pop the number 4 out of the array
print "The array is now $array[-1].\n";
```

Comment: What do you expect `pop @array, 4;` to do?

Comment: you didn't use strict, you didn't use warnings.

Comment: You should always enable warnings when developing Perl code.

Comment: I expect pop @array, 4 to pop the number 4 from the array, and print out the array as so 1,2,3,5,6.

Comment: @DopeBP, added that interpretation to my post.

Comment: Completely aside from anything about perl, popping a stack doesn't extract a specific element, it removes the most recently pushed element, whatever its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of a stack is you can only access items from the top. You can only push an item onto the top of stack or pop an item off the top of the stack.  The elements in the middle are not accessible.  Using Perl's shift and unshift functions you can also implement queues and dequeues (or double-ended queues.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = 1..5;

push @array, 6;
push @array, 7;

my $top = pop @array;

print "Top was $top\n";
print "Remainder of array is ", join(", ", @array), "\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

First things first, use `use strict; use warnings;`.

What's `pop @array, 4;` supposed to do?

Pop four elements?

```
splice(@array, -4);
```

Replace the last element with the value 4?

```
$array[-1] = 4;
```

Filter out the value 4?

```
@array = grep { $_ != 4 } @array;
```

Reference:

- [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html)
- [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)
- [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

---

By the way, `#usr/bin/perl` is meaningless. It should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

By the way, the escape sequence for a newline is `\n`, not `/n`.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax: `pop @array, 4;`

[***pop***](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) should take at most, one argument (the array).  It will pop the last element from the array stack, whereas [***shift***](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) takes the first element from the stack.

Comment: It's probably equivalent to `pop(@array), 4;`, using a comma operator.

Comment: Yeah, whereas based on his description, he wants to splice out the element that contains the value `4`